# use both html and php in echo and href line

Tags: php, html, echo, string-concatenation

I have the variable:

```
 $myvar = 'myarchive.pdf';
```

How can I embedd it to this:

```
echo('<tr> <td> <a href="nextpage.php?file=trial.pdf"> download now </a> </td> </tr>');
```

I wonder if there is a way to do it like this:

```
 echo('<tr> <td> <a href="nextpage.php?file=".'$myvar'.> download now </a> </td> </tr>');
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not appending the variable to the string properly. Also you have to enclose *nextpage.php?file=variable* within quotes. But you are closing it before the variable name.

```
<a href="nextpage.php?file=".'$myvar'.>
                           ^
```

So try with

```
echo('<tr> <td> <a href="nextpage.php?file='.$myvar.'"> download now </a> </td> </tr>');
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
echo('<tr> <td> <a href="nextpage.php?file='.$myvar.'> download now </a> </td> </tr>');
```

Answer (score 0):

this should work. re-add your brackets if you must

```
echo '<tr><td><a href="nextpage.php?file='.$myvar.'">download now</a></td></tr>';
```