# html source path with variable

Tags: php, html

I write a PHP - HTML project and a have to be able to depict some videos. Thus, I store the same of the video like this:

```
$myVideoName = "Video1.mp4" //video in local host
```

and I wrote a simple video script to embed it to a browser:

```
<div style="text-align:center">
<video id="Video1" width='500' height='500' controls >
<source src='.\MyProject\Video1.mp4' type='video/mp4'>
</video>
</div>
```

Now I want to embed the variable of the video to the source path code like this:

```
<source src='.\MyProject\'.$myVideoName type='video/mp4'>
```

What is the right way to do so?

Comment: Obviously you just took the [code here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23758365/447356) and never even bothered to read it. So read the code, *learn what it does* and you'll have your answer here as well. People should not always give you everything on a silver plate.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the page which contains the video tag is of `.php` extension, to use variables inside a string, you can do something like this:

```
<source src=".\MyProject\<?php echo $myVideoName; ?>" type="video/mp4">
```

Answer (score 0):

If `$myVideoName` is not changing say `$myVideoName = "Video1.mp4"` then you will do like this :

```
<source src=".\MyProject\<?php echo $myVideoName;?>" type="video/mp4">
```

if the videos data is in some table then you have to fetch the data from that table to this variable `$myVideoName`

You have to save this file with extension `.php` otherwise it won't work

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this.

```
<?php
    echo '<source src="\MyProject\'.$myVideoName.'" type="video/mp4">';
?>
```